# Bootstrap Carousel Customization

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Hi I have a bootstrap carousel on my site that I customize but it's not good when I resize the screen to smaller (responsive testing) it is overlapping the image

full screen size
[image]

resize screen
[image]

This is my Bootstrap Code

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                      <div class="carousel-inner">

                                <div class="item active col-lg-12">
                                 <div class="col-lg-6"><img src="//placehold.it/450x300" alt="folder" class="img-resposnive"></div>
                                  <div class="col-lg-6 carousel-caption">
                                    <p>
                                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
                                    </p>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-green"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Request Access to Private Beta</button>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                  <div class="col-lg-6"><img src="//placehold.it/450x300" alt="folder" class="img-resposnive"></div>
                                  <div class="col-lg-6 carousel-caption">
                                    <p>
                                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
                                    </p>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-green"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Request Access to Private Beta</button>                                 
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                  <div class="col-lg-6"><img src="//placehold.it/450x300" alt="folder" class="img-resposnive"></div>
                                  <div class="col-lg-6 carousel-caption">
                                    <p>
                                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
                                    </p>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-green"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Request Access to Private Beta</button>                                 
                                  </div>
                                </div>

                      </div>

                      <!-- Controls -->
                      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                      </a>
                      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This is my CSS

```
.carousel {
 margin-bottom: 60px;
 }
 /* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
 z-index: 10;
 }

 /* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
 .carousel-inner > .item > img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 min-width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 }

.carousel-control.left {
  background-image: none;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  }

.carousel-control.right {
  background-image: none;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  }

.carousel .item {
  background-color: #4A2485;
  height: 300px;
 }

.carousel-control {
width:auto;
 }

.carousel-caption {
  left: 45%;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  right: 20%;
  text-align:left;
  color:#bababa;
  text-shadow:none;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already a class "col-lg-6". So that should work properly. Your problem is here-

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
```

This **position: absolute** property overriding the default CSS styling of BS. So remove this. Another alternative could be a custom media query.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure but what is going to happen if you take out the

min-width: 100%;
 height: 300px;

From your .carousel-inner > .item > img  ?

Because you allready give the picture a size in your bootstrap script, so adding new sizes to your css will overwrite the style from your bootstrap...So just give it a try

Comment: You are near to the problem. Just look **position: absolute**. This is the main problem.

Comment: Yeah I just realised it after taking a look at the script again...thanks for your correction

Answer (score 0):

Add `class="img img-responsive"` to all the images. The class name is misspelt that's why the *CSS* isn't working correctly.

And regarding the columns, you could add `md`, `sm` and `xs` classes depending on the target devices. There's no custom *CSS* required for the carousel. This should take care of your issues.